# flutter refresh widget's content but it remains old data

Tags: flutter

**[SOLVED]** Check the listview builder's data source.

I want to refresh the content of Column, but when I remove a item and add a new item to the *todoFutureBuilder*, the UI still shows the old data(And new data after old data). Why this happens? What should I do to refresh the content?

**code**

init method

```
  List<Widget> todoFutureBuilder=[];
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    todoFutureBuilder.add(Text('This is result'));
    super.initState();
  }
```

build method

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          getSearchBar(),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              children: todoFutureBuilder,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

method to change the content of Widget.

```
  showSearchArtistResults() {
    setState(() {
      if(todoFutureBuilder.length!=1){
        todoFutureBuilder.removeAt(1); 
      }
      print(todoFutureBuilder);
    });
    setState(() {
        todoFutureBuilder.add(
            FutureBuilder(
              future: getSearchArtistResultList(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  print(snapshot.data);
                  if (snapshot.data == 'have_result') {
                    return Expanded(child: buildArtistResultList());
                  } else {
                    return Text('No Result, Please Search Again');
                  }
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                }
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              },
            )
        );
        print(todoFutureBuilder);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use `todoFutureBuilder.clear()` function

Comment: it doesn't work. In fact debugger shows that the todoFutureBuilder is [Text("Result"), FutureBuilder<String>], Just contains 2 widget, but the screen still shows 3(or more)

Comment: if(todoFutureBuilder.length!=1){ 
      } Maybe this restriction causes an error

Comment: I found the problem. I use another list to store data and I forget to refresh it, while the widget list is OK. thank you.